# Cannot assign retreived POSTed parameters to a Variable

Tags: parameters

I am trying to retreive parameters POSTed to my page from a Server, I have tried this in my Page_Load (VB.Net):

```vb
Dim strTemp as String
strTemp = Request.Params("ID").ToString
'strTemp = Request("ID")
'strTemp = Page.Request.Form("ID")
```

All of the above methods do show a value in the Request object when I breakpoint and hold
my cursor on them (So, I know my page is getting them), but I cannot get them to assign to a variable like so:

```vb
Dim strTemp as string = Request.Params("ID").ToString
```

The `strTemp` variable is always nothing!

My test page markup is simple and just looks like this:

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="GolfAnywhere.Test1"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID"  />
        <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <div> </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="GolfAnywhere.Test1"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID"  />
            <div> </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whatever you want to send, keep it inside form.